# Error handling with Mongoose

Tags: rest, error-handling, mongoose

I am an absolute NodeJS beginner and want to create a simple REST-Webservice with Express and Mongoose.

Whats the best practice to handle errors of Mongoose in one central place?

When anywhere an database error occurs I want to return a Http-500-Error-Page with an error message:

```
if(error) {
  res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.write('{error: "' + error + '"}');
  res.end();
}
```

In the old tutorial http://blog-next-stage.learnboost.com/mongoose/ I read about an global error listener:

```
Mongoose.addListener('error',function(errObj,scope_of_error));
```

But this doesn't seem to work and I cannot find something in the [official Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) about this listener. Have I check for errors after every Mongo request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler and more up to date solution IMO:

### Connection errors

Handle connection level errors when you instantiate your db:

```js
const mongooseConnection = mongoose.createConnection(databaseURL)

mongooseConnection.on('error', err => {
  throw new Error('Mongo database connexion error')
})
```

### Query level errors

Query level errors may appear if you write fields with wrong types or use query options (populate, sort...) incorrectly. We can use a more readable/up to date `try catch await` over the old `promise.callback.catch` syntax ([mongoose doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html))

```js
try {
  await Band.findOne({ _id: badId }).exec();
} catch (err) {
  throw new Error('Mongo database connexion error')
}
```

---

### BONUS: advices and good practices

**=> Use an error handler across all your app**

Error handling in the 2 example above are not very relevant because you loose all contextual informations (mongo error msg, stack trace, database name, userId...)

You may handle errors in a centralized way so that you can pass contextual informations alongside the error message like so:

```js
try { ... } catch (err) {
  throw ApplicationError(
    'myMessage',
    {
      // Here we pass additional informations
      // this will help handling the error on the express api side
      httpCode: err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError ? 422 : 500,
      // with this one you can display original error messsage/stack trace
      originalError: err, 
      // other contextual informations may be useful to display
      // but be carreful not to display sensitive informations
      // here (Eg DB connection string)
      databaseName,
      userId,
      userRole,
      methodName,
    }
  )
}

class ApplicationError extends Error {
  constructor(errMsg, additionalInfos) {
    // Here handle error as you want
  }
}
```

[List of all error types thrown by mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/error.html)

**=> Use a request handler to handle all mongoose queries the same way**

A common pattern to avoid duplicating code is to create a function to handle the execution of mongoose promise for you:

```js
async function afterRequest(mongoosePromise, { sort, page, limit }) {
  try {
    if (sort) promise.sort(sort)

    // PAGINATION
    if (page) promise.skip(localConfig.page * limit || 25).limit(limit || 25)
    else if (limit) promise.limit(limit)

    return await promise.exec()

  } catch (err) { /** handle error like in the above code */ }
}
```

So we can now use it like:

```js
const mongoosePromise = Band.find()
afterRequest(mongoosePromise, { page: 1, limit: 10 })
```

This pattern has the advantage of:

- handling all in the same place, so it's the safest place to add custom code for security handling or validation for example
- easily exposing some options like pagination... to api or some services that you may not want to deal directly with mongoose requests

The above is juste a very simplified example, but to go further, here are some features we could implement:

- check if the user has the permission to populate
- masking certain fields in filter or updated/created fields related to user permissions (a simple user may not been able to write his permissions for example)
- force certain filters (companyAdmin may have access only to their company so we want to enforce filter `{ companyId: user.companyId }`
- ...

Answer (score 48):

If you're using Express, errors are typically handled either directly in your route or within an api built on top of mongoose, forwarding the error along to `next`.

```js
app.get('/tickets', function (req, res, next) {
  PlaneTickets.find({}, function (err, tickets) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    // or if no tickets are found maybe
    if (0 === tickets.length) return next(new NotFoundError));
    ...
  })
})
```

The `NotFoundError` could be sniffed in your [error handler middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html) to provide customized messaging.

Some abstraction is possible but you'll still require access to the `next` method in order to pass the error down the route chain.

```js
PlaneTickets.search(term, next, function (tickets) {
    // i don't like this b/c it hides whats going on and changes the (err, result) callback convention of node
})
```

As for centrally handling mongoose errors, theres not really one place to handle em all. Errors can be handled at several different levels:

`connection` errors are emitted on the `connection` your models are using, so

```js
mongoose.connect(..);
mongoose.connection.on('error', handler);

// or if using separate connections
var conn = mongoose.createConnection(..);
conn.on('error', handler);
```

For typical queries/updates/removes the error is passed to your callback.

```js
PlaneTickets.find({..}, function (err, tickets) {
    if (err) ...
```

If you don't pass a callback the error is emitted on the Model *if you are listening for it:*

```js
PlaneTickets.on('error', handler); // note the loss of access to the `next` method from the request!
ticket.save(); // no callback passed
```

If you do not pass a callback and are not listening to errors at the `model` level they will be emitted on the models `connection`.

The key take-away here is that you want access to `next` somehow to pass the error along.

Comment: Thanks, your helpful answer clarifies a lot about error handling for me.

Comment: Great answer! Especially the suggestion about using next() to tie directly into ExpressJS's error handling middleware.

Comment: That doesn't works with mongoose.connection.on('error', handler); or conn.on('error', handler); for me, I defined handler as a function that console.log() the first arg but nothing appears on the server console.

Comment: seems new version of Mongoose (4.4) has removed this, i tried Model.on or Conn.on, none will be notified if an error happened during query.

Answer (score 0):

hey this is the simplest way i found..

```
try { } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // checking validation
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
        
        const message = Object.values(error.errors).map(value => value.message);
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: message
        })
    }
    res.status(400).json(error.message)
}
```

}

just copy paste