# Mongoose connection error reporting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to throw my own error if mongoose cannot connect to or find mongoDB.

The latest I've tried is:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/numaria');
db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'THIS ERROR WONT SHOW'));

db.once('open', function(){
  console.log(clc.blackBright(new Date()) + ': ' + clc.cyan('Connected') + ' to ' + clc.yellow('MongoDB'));
});
```

What I expect: `THIS ERROR WONT SHOW`

What I get:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

with a reference to a mongoose module file

---

I've been all over SO and I've tried all of these but to no avail:

- [is there a mongoose connect error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676499/is-there-a-mongoose-connect-error-callback)
- [Mongoose Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360531/mongoose-connection)
- [Error handling with Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864482/error-handling-with-mongoose)

This is the mongoose entry:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/

I've also tried surrounding with `try{}catch(err){})`

Finally, if I do spin up the DB, everything works fine.

---

**edit**

@glortho explained *"If MongoDB is not running at all then you can't even get to the connection error layer as you've bound it."*

Is there a way to better throw the error in mongoose of not finding MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting first. Try this instead:

```
db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'THIS ERROR WONT SHOW'));

db.once('open', function(){
  console.log(clc.blackBright(new Date()) + ': ' + clc.cyan('Connected') + ' to ' + clc.yellow('MongoDB'));
});

try {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/numaria');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Great thought, but it still throws the unhandled error. Also the second SO post i checked up there connects first and they accepted :/

Comment: Hmm. I edited to include `try` block. What happens then?

Comment: Still no cigar. I also tried the callback `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/numaria', function(err){console.log(err);})` and got nothing... let me try to throw that in a try block.

Comment: Yea I still got nothing :(

Comment: It must be failing to connect via that port or something, not getting to MongoDB at all.

Comment: Ah. Try running MongoDB and specify a bogus DB to connect to. Then you should get your error. If MongoDB is not running at all then you can't even get to the connection error layer as you've bound it.

Comment: Understood, is there a better way to report the error of it not detecting MongoDB?

Comment: You really should be able to capture that connection failure error in a callback like the one you tried in your "no cigar" comment above. If not, and no other captures work, I'm not sure what to tell you!

Comment: Dang, leave this up so people will know what I've tried. Thanks for everything! At least this tells me this problem is definitely above me.