# Global and general Error Handling of Mongoose with Express?

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm building an Express API Server with Mongoose,

with Express i'm catching all errors and response with the error message

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).json({message: err.message})
})
```

But with Mongoose, i should pass each Error manually to next() each time when i do a query.

Is there any way that make mongoose throw the error to next() automatically so that i could never concern about the error handling of a query anymore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error handling with Mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864482/error-handling-with-mongoose)

Comment: @ZeMoon Thanks, but i read this before i posted my question. It doesn't work for me probably because of the old version of mongoose. it has been 3 years after that question was posted