# Error handling with get route with mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, error-handling

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const course = await Course.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!course) {
    return res.status(400).send(`course id is invaild`);
  }
  res.send(course);
});
```

As you guys can see, this is a very simple route function.
It works fine if it got the right id but once I gave it the wrong id it throws this error on my console

```
GET /api/courses/600f4aab118a6c5ef60fb5f7 200 75 - 20.069 ms
(node:32606) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to
ObjectId failed for value "600f4aab118a6c5ef60fb5f7a" at path "_id"
for model "Course"
    at model.Query.exec (/home/hesham/Desktop/test-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4358:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/home/hesham/Desktop/test-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4452:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) 

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:32606)
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
with .catch().
To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).

(rejection id: 1) (node:32606) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864482/error-handling-with-mongoose

Comment: error is very straight forward, you are not passing object id or invalid value which cannot be cast as object id, furthermore you are not handling mongoose exceptions